# Module Not showing when redis is activated

Tags: magento-1.9

im using redis on my store, but im having some issues. Im using a module (ex: giftcard), but for some reason when i have redis activated my module disapears. I already tried to flush redis, and at first shows the module activated in the backed, but after some minutes, disapears. The module shows only if a clear cache. The only way to fix it is if a disable redis permantly.

Above i leave my redis local code, maybe someone can figure out what is wrong.

```
 <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
         <cache>
          <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
          <backend_options>
            <server>redis04.local</server>                               <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent>                                <!-- Specify unique string to enable persistent connections. E.g.: sess-db0; bugs with phpredis and php-fpm are known: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/70 -->
            <database>0</database>                                   <!-- Redis database number; protection against accidental data loss is improved by not sharing databases -->
            <password></password>                                    <!-- Specify if your Redis server requires authentication -->
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>                   <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>                     <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures; a value of 1 will not retry after the first failure -->
            <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>                          <!-- Set read timeout duration; phpredis does not currently support setting read timeouts -->
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>                         <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>                         <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>           <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>                  <!-- Support gzip, lzf, lz4 (https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-lz4) or snappy (https://github.com/goatherd/php-snappy) -->
            <use_lua>0</use_lua>                                     <!-- Set to 1 if Lua scripts should be used for some operations -->
          </backend_options>
        </cache>
        <redis_session>                                          <!-- All options seen here are the defaults -->
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>                               <!-- Specify an absolute path if using a unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <password></password>                                <!-- Specify if your Redis server requires authentication -->
            <timeout>2.5</timeout>                               <!-- This is the Redis connection timeout, not the locking timeout -->
            <persistent></persistent>                            <!-- Specify unique string to enable persistent connections. E.g.: sess-db0; bugs with phpredis and php-fpm are known: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/70 -->
            <db>0</db>                                           <!-- Redis database number; protection from accidental loss is improved by using a unique DB number for sessions -->
            <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>  <!-- Set to 0 to disable compression (recommended when suhosin.session.encrypt=on); known bug with strings over 64k: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/issues/18 -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>              <!-- gzip, lzf, lz4 (https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-lz4) or snappy (https://github.com/goatherd/php-snappy) -->
            <log_level>1</log_level>                             <!-- 0 (emergency: system is unusable), 4 (warning; additional information, recommended), 5 (notice: normal but significant condition), 6 (info: informational messages), 7 (debug: the most information for development/testing) -->
            <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>                 <!-- maximum number of processes that can wait for a lock on one session; for large production clusters, set this to at least 10% of the number of PHP processes -->
            <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>       <!-- seconds to wait for a session lock in the frontend; not as critical as admin -->
            <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
            <first_lifetime>600</first_lifetime>                 <!-- Lifetime of session for non-bots on the first write. 0 to disable -->
            <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>          <!-- Lifetime of session for bots on the first write. 0 to disable -->
            <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>                    <!-- Lifetime of session for bots on subsequent writes. 0 to disable -->
            <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>                 <!-- Disable session locking entirely. -->
            <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>                      <!-- Set the minimum session lifetime -->
            <max_lifetime>2592000</max_lifetime>                 <!-- Set the maximum session lifetime -->
        </redis_session>
```